# How to get Country Area Code like India(+91) in php by API

Tags: php

How to get Country Area Code like `India(+91)` in php by API

could not find by this

```
$detailsId=json_decode(file_get_contents('http://ipinfo.io/'.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']));
```

---

I got fron this.

```
 $idd=json_decode(file_get_contents('https://restcountries.eu/rest/v1/alpha?codes=IN'));
```

Comment: any solution you have or you are just editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
$detailsId=json_decode(file_get_contents('http://ipinfo.io/'.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']));
```

to get the data of your country, and you can call

```
https://restcountries.eu/rest/v1/name/india
```

You can also get the currency and data you needed.